# How to manage an output to put only one "1" even when entry stay up?

Tags: fpga, vhdl

I'm a beginner with VHDL and electronics, I'm trying to do something like this:

input list: i_button1 : it's the value of the entry button (1,0)

output list : o_button1_sync : it's the value of the output linked with entry (1,0)

The use case is the entry can be 1 all the time so it would send in i_button1 : 1,1,1,1,1 but the output need to send only a single time a 1, so o_button1_sync would send 1,0,0,0,0,0 until the entry go back to 0 and 1 again

entry 1,1,1 -> output 1,0,0 // entry 1,1,0,1,0,1,1 -> output 1,0,0,1,0,1,0

I tried to use a Mealy machine with two state Pressed and noPressure and I think the problem is in the 2nd process

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity Button1_sync is
   port (   i_button1        : in    std_logic;
            i_clk        : in    std_logic;
            i_clk_game        : in    std_logic;
            i_rst      : in    std_logic;
            o_button1_sync  : out   std_logic);
end Button1_sync;

architecture BEHAVIORAL of Button1_sync is
    type stateType is (noPressure, Pressed);
    signal state, nextState : stateType;

begin
    -- 1st process: memorise the state
   process(i_clk_game,i_rst)
      begin
          if (i_rst = '1') then
              state <= noPressure;
          elsif rising_edge(i_clk_game) then
              state <= nextState;
          end if;
   end process;
   -- ---------------------------------------------------
   -- 2nd process: for the futur state
    process (state, i_button1)
    begin
        case state is
            when noPressure =>
                if i_button1 = '1' then
                    nextState <= Pressed;
                else
                    nextState <= noPressure;
                end if;
            when Pressed =>
                if i_button1 = '1' then
                    nextState <= noPressure;
                else
                    nextState <= Pressed;
                end if;
            when others =>
                nextState <= noPressure;
        end case;
    end process;
    -- ----------------------------------------------------
    -- 3rd process: combinatory for the output
    process(state) --, nextState, i_button1
    begin
        --s <= '1' when (state = A and t = '1');
        case state is
            when Pressed =>
                if i_button1 = '1' then
                     o_button1_sync <= '0';
                else
                    o_button1_sync <= '1';
                end if;
            when noPressure=>
                if i_button1 = '1' then
                     o_button1_sync <= '1';
                else
                    o_button1_sync <= '0';
                end if;
            when others => o_button1_sync <= '0';
        end case;
    end process;
 end Behavioral;
```

When I simulate I have this result :
[image]

but it should send instantly on the next i_clk_game rising edge the value "1" in output for one clock period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler solution would be to use an edge detect circuit such as that below. Note that you may also need to resynchronise the i_button1 input to avoid the flip flop going meta stable.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff0a5i.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I solved this hell with a 3rd state :

````
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity Button1_sync is
   port (   i_button1        : in    std_logic;
            i_clk        : in    std_logic;
            i_clk_game        : in    std_logic;
            i_rst      : in    std_logic;
            o_button1_sync  : out   std_logic);
end Button1_sync;

architecture BEHAVIORAL of Button1_sync is
    type stateType is (noPressure, Pressed, Pressed_sync0);
    signal state, nextState : stateType;

begin
    -- 1er process : registre qui mémorise l’état présent
   process(i_clk_game,i_rst)
      begin
          if (i_rst = '1') then
              state <= noPressure;
          elsif rising_edge(i_clk_game) then
              state <= nextState;
          end if;
   end process;
   -- ---------------------------------------------------
   -- 2ème process : circuit combinatoire pour l’état futur
    process (state, i_button1)
    begin
        case state is
            when noPressure =>
                if i_button1 = '1' then
                    nextState <= Pressed;
                else
                    nextState <= noPressure;
                end if;
            when Pressed =>
                if i_button1 = '1' then
                    nextState <= Pressed_sync0;
                else
                    nextState <= noPressure;
                end if;
            when Pressed_sync0 => 
                if i_button1 = '1' then
                    nextState <= Pressed_sync0;
                else
                    nextState <= noPressure;
                end if;
            when others =>
                nextState <= noPressure;
        end case;
    end process;
    -- ----------------------------------------------------
    -- 3ème process : circuit combinatoire pour les sorties
    process(state) --, nextState, i_button1
    begin
        --s <= '1' when (state = A and t = '1');
        case state is
            when Pressed =>
                if i_button1 = '1' then
                     o_button1_sync <= '1';
                else
                    o_button1_sync <= '0';
                end if;
            when noPressure=>
                if i_button1 = '1' then
                     o_button1_sync <= '1';
                else
                    o_button1_sync <= '0';
                end if;
            when others => o_button1_sync <= '0';
        end case;
    end process;
 end Behavioral;

```
````